# TSQL Min and Max date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with columns DateTime, JobID, TaskID

```
DateTime                 JobID            TaskID
2020-05-16 06:43:11.687   353              NULL
2020-05-16 06:45:11.687   353              123
2020-05-16 06:43:11.687   353              123
2020-05-16 06:43:12.297   353              456
2020-05-16 06:44:30.750   353              456
2020-05-16 06:44:30.750   353              456
2020-05-16 06:44:30.750   353              789
2020-05-16 06:45:05.000   353              789
2020-05-16 06:48:07.750   353              789
2020-05-16 06:49:01:110   353              011
2020-05-16 06:50:11:112   353              NULL
```

I need to write query that gives me the min(datetime) of child taskID 456 and max(datetime) of parent jobId 353, the output needs to look like

```
Startime                     Endtime
2020-05-16 06:43:12.297      2020-05-16 06:50:11:112
```

This is for just one day, i.e. 16th, similarly I need one weeks data. I tried doing a join on same table

```
select 
mt1.Starttime, MAX(t1.JobLogDateTime) AS Endtime
from 
JobLog t1
inner join (
    SELECT jobid, MIN(JobLogDateTime) AS Starttime
    FROM JobLog WHERE taskid=456
    group by JobLogDateTime, jobid

) mt1
    on t1.JobID=mt1.jobid
    GROUP BY t1.JobLogDateTime
```

This is creating a problem due to incorrect group by clause , I also tried:

```
SELECT FORMAT(jbl.JobLogDateTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS mainrundate, 
child.starttime, 
MAX(joblogdatetime) FROM JobLog jbl INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT FORMAT(JobLogDateTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS rundate, MIN(joblogdatetime) 
AS Starttime FROM JobLog 
WHERE TaskID=456
GROUP BY FORMAT(joblogdatetime, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
) child ON child.rundate=jbl.mainrundate 
GROUP BY child.starttime, FORMAT(jbl.JobLogDateTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
ORDER BY FORMAT(jbl.JobLogDateTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd') desc
```

but it says the Join is incorrect

Comment: [Don't use `FORMAT()` for that style](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but). Use `CONVERT(char(10), col_name, 120)`. For the grouping and ordering I would even prefer `CONVERT(date, col_name)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by changing my query as below:

```
SELECT FORMAT(jbl.JobLogDateTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS JobRunDate, MIN(child.starttime) 
AS Startime, MAX(jbl.joblogdatetime) AS EndTime
FROM JobLog jbl left JOIN 
(
SELECT  joblogdatetime AS Starttime FROM JobLog 
WHERE TaskID=456
) child ON child.Starttime=jbl.JobLogDateTime
WHERE jobid=353 
GROUP BY FORMAT(jbl.JobLogDateTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
ORDER BY FORMAT(jbl.JobLogDateTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd') desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need also to group by jobid in the main query and then add the group by the field from the subquery, t1.JobLogDateTime is the field you are aggregating, not the one you are grouping, same thing in the subquery, if you do MIN(X) you can't also GRUOP BY X.
Try using this :

```
select 
t1.jobid, mt1.Starttime, MAX(t1.JobLogDateTime) AS Endtime
from 
JobLog t1
inner join (
    SELECT jobid, MIN(JobLogDateTime) AS Starttime
    FROM JobLog WHERE taskid=456
    group by jobid
) mt1
    on t1.JobID=mt1.jobid      
    GROUP BY t1.jobid, mt1.StartTime
```

I also removed the dot at the end of 't1.JobID=mt1.jobid', think it's a typo

EDIT: a couple of edit.. my first post and the format wasn't very nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WITH child
     AS (SELECT taskid, 
                MIN(JobLogDateTime) AS Endtime
         FROM JobLog
         WHERE taskid = 456
         GROUP BY taskid)

SELECT MAX(j.JobLogDateTime) AS Startime, 
    MIN(c.Endtime) AS Endtime
FROM JobLog AS j
JOIN child AS c ON j.TaskID = c.TaskID;
```

Comment: This could work if data was needed for one day, but i am looking for start end times for a week

Comment: just add "JobLogDateTime between <start looking date> and <end looking date>" filters to WHERE clause in both SELECT statements

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT 
    min( datetime ) OVER ( task_id )
    , max( datetime ) OVER ( task_id )
FROM 
    X
WHERE 
    job_id = y
```